# Append part of PHP while loop to a div

Tags: php, html, mysql, loops, while-loop

Assume I have this simple PHP MYSQL while loop:

```
<?php
while($row = $STH->fetch())
{
echo '<div id="$row['id']">$row['content']</div>';

echo '<div id="comment-holder">;
echo '<div id="$row['id2']">$row['content2']</div>'; 
echo '</div>';   

echo '<div id="$row['id3']">$row['content3']</div>';  

?>
```

How to make the `comment-holder` DIV act like a holder? meaning that it should be echoed only once and content of `$row[id2]` a `$row[content2]` should be appended to it to appear like this:

```
 <div id="comment-holder">
 <div id="1">test</div> 
 <div id="2">different</div>
 <div id="3">text</div>  
 </div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I hope your syntax isn't that messed up in your actual code. The `comment-holder` line is missing a `'` at the end.

Comment: sorry didn't realize these mistakes...actual code not messed of course :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ones = $twos = $threes = '';

while ($row = $STH->fetch()) {
    $ones .= "<div id='$row[id]'>$row[content]</div>";
    $twos .= "<div id='$row[id2]'>$row[content2]</div>";
    $threes .= "<div id='$row[id3]'>$row[content3]</div>";
}

$result = sprintf("%s<div id='comment-holder'>%s</div>%s", $ones, $twos, $threes)
```

Comment: not all the divs should be surrounded by the comment-holder...only the contents of column id2 and column content2...that's why in my question i echoed one before and one after...and that's the problem...how to make the comment holder appear only once between 2 divs and the append content of column id2 and content2 to it

Comment: @MichaelSamuel I understood you .. my answer should do that.  Did you even try it?

Answer (score 2):

At first: your code has errors - in single quoted strings is not string interpolation.
If you want that structure, you can simple surround your code with the given div

```
<div class="comment-holder">
<?php
while($row = $STH->fetch())
{
echo "<div id=\"{$row['id']}\">{$row['content']}</div>";
echo "<div id=\"{$row['id2']}\">{$row['content2']}</div>";
echo "<div id=\"{$row['id3']}\">{$row['content3']}</div>";  
}
?>
</div>
```

Or:

```
<?php
echo '<div class="comment-holder">';
while($row = $STH->fetch())
{
    echo "<div id=\"{$row['id']}\">{$row['content']}</div>";
    echo "<div id=\"{$row['id2']}\">{$row['content2']}</div>";
    echo "<div id=\"{$row['id3']}\">{$row['content3']}</div>";  
}
echo '</div>';
?>
```

Comment: You have `comment-holder` also inside the loop

Comment: comment-holder itself is surrounded by other code that's being echoed also

Comment: you can put `<div class..>` also in an echo statement and write it before the while loop and echo `</div>` after the while loop..

Comment: Sorry you can't understand me the there is div before and div after the comment-holder...those 2 divs have also dynamic content being outputted from the database so they should be included inside the while loop and special content should be appended to the comment-holder

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something pretty obvious here or something but... why don't you just change the order of the echoes?

```
<?php
while($row = $STH->fetch())
{

echo '<div id="comment-holder">';
echo '<div id="' . $row['id'] . '">' . $row['content'] . '</div>';
echo '<div id="' . $row['id2'] . '">' . $row['content2'] . '</div>'; 
echo '<div id="' . $row['id3'] . '">' . $row['content3'] . '</div>';  
echo '</div>';   

?>
```

By the way, where does the `while` block end?

Comment: Forgot to end the loop....the first echo is different from the last one and the the divs inside the comment-holder are also different from the first and last echo..so the holder should be printed between 2 other divs

Answer (score -1):

Put it outside the while loop. Ex.

```
<?php
    echo 'hi';
    for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
        echo 'yo';
    }
    echo 'the end';
?>
```

Will output: hi yo yo yo yo yo the end

Comment: can't do it like this because there are other divs that should be echoed in the while loop also and the comments-holder is between them